# How to copy data as image to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How to copy data with vba excel  from sheet A range a1 : i24 (including combo box) to sheet B range j1 as image and full protect. Because source mean sheet A not protected

Comment: Hi @user10792618, it would be helpful if you also added what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, if you need help implementing it add some code to your question and let me know.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial

### Example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F5").PasteSpecial _ 
Format:="Picture (PNG)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: 'Wsdata.range ("a1:i24").copy
Wsdata1.range("a1").select
Activesheet.pastespecial format:="result object"
Range ("b2").select